# org.apache.poi for xls write number format issue

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

My java program uses org.apache.poi for writing xls document. xls file gets generated with proper number formats with XL 2010 but with XL 2013 number is not getting formatted and it shows 6 digits after decimal point

Example:
In xl 2010 12.123445 shows as 12.12 which is expected

In xl 2013 12.123445 shows as 12.123225 which is not expected it should round two two digits after decimal.

I have tried upgrading my org.apage.poi pom.xml with latest 3.14, 3.16-beta2.

Currently using 3.10-FINAL.

Any idea how to fix it ? Or any org.apache.poi method available for xl cell value to set it as number with rounding to 2 digits after decimal.

Code snippet:

```
style = createStyle(sheet.getWorkbook(), (short) 10, fontWeight, fontColor);

                Double number = Double.parseDouble(colHeader);
                cell.setCellValue(number);
                style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.00"));
                cell.setCellStyle(style);



createStyle():
protected HSSFCellStyle createStyle(Workbook wb, short fontSize, short boldWeight, short fontColor) {

        Font font = fontMap.get(getMapKey(fontSize, boldWeight, fontColor));

        if (font == null) {
            font = wb.createFont();
            font.setFontHeightInPoints(fontSize);
            font.setFontName("Arial");
            font.setBoldweight(boldWeight);
            font.setColor(fontColor);
            fontMap.put(getMapKey(fontSize, boldWeight, fontColor), font);
        }
        HSSFCellStyle style = ((HSSFWorkbook) wb).createCellStyle();
        style.setFont(font);
        return style;
    }
```

Comment: could you please shard your code?

Comment: Here is the code snippet:

Answer (score 0):

I create a executable example with poi-bin-3.15-20160924 Jars that formatted a double from (12.123445) to (12.12)
and (12.125) to (12.13) :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;


public class WriteReadXlsFormula {

public static void main(String[] args){

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Calculate Simple Interest");
    //To format a double
    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
     style.setDataFormat(
                workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.00"));

    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Pricipal Amount (P)");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Rate of Interest (r)");
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Tenure (t)");
    header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Interest (P r t)");

    //Don't use the style and use DicimalFormat (comment 3 line of code under Cell contain the number to format comment)
    /*
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.00");
    dataRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(df.format(12.125445)); 
    */


    Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(1);
    dataRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(14500d);

    //Cell contain the number to format 
    dataRow.createCell(1).setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
    dataRow.getCell(1).setCellStyle(style);
    dataRow.getCell(1).setCellValue(df1.format(12.125445));

    dataRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(3d);
    dataRow.createCell(3).setCellFormula("A2*B2*C2");



    try {
        FileOutputStream out = 
                new FileOutputStream(new File("formula.xls"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        workbook.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code it got well executed in local as stand alone program.

Comment: Thank you for the code it got well executed in local as stand alone program. But issue is the value which is passed to set as two digits after decimal is of type String as below ------------------------------------------------ for (String colHeader : wbd.getFC()) {
            cell = row.createCell(colIdx);

            style = createStyle(sheet.getWorkbook(), (short) 10, fontWeight, fontColor);
                Double number = Double.parseDouble(colHeader);                       I have tried setCellStyle(style); by setting setDataFormat as you mention but it did not work on server.

Comment: Did you set the cell where you put the  number to setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC); before applying the style.

Comment: or use DecimalFormat,

Comment: BigDecimal has worked without any warning message. BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number);
   bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
       cell.setCellValue(bd.doubleValue());